# FFmpeg '-bframebias' option gone?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Recently I updated ffmpeg to version 1.1, when I run a command containing `bframebias`, it showed an error:

```
Unrecognized option 'bframebias'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

This command used to work fine. So the option `bframebias` is removed or it is replaced by another option?

```
C:\Users\Raymond\Downloads\ffmpeg-1.1-win32-static\bin>ffmpeg -i C:\Users\Raymon
d\Desktop\IntroductiontoITILREAD2.wmv -vcodec libx264 -r 25 -b:v 1500k -profile:
v main -level 41 -bf 3 -direct-pred auto -b_strategy 1 -weightb 1 -bidir_refine
1 -b-pyramid none -bframebias 0 -8x8dct 0 -partitions i8x8,i4x4,p8x8,p4x4,b8x8 -
maxrate 24000k -bufsize 24000k -bt 1.0 -qcomp 0.60 -me_range 16 -sc_threshold 40
 -me_method hex -subq 7 -cmp chroma -qmax 69 -qmin 10 -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_qfactor
 0.77 -trellis 0 -refs 2 -mixed-refs 0 -coder 1 -fast-pskip 1 -flags +loop -debl
ock 0:0 -rc-lookahead 40 -mbtree 1 -psy 1 -slices 0 -slice-max-size 0 -preset fa
st -acodec libvo_aacenc -profile:a aac_low -ar 48000 -ab 128000 -ac 2 -s 720x576
 -aspect 16:9 -f matroska C:\Users\Raymond\Desktop\OUTPUT.mkv

ffmpeg version 1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan  8 2013 16:10:57 with gcc 4.7.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libg
sm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --e
nable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --e
nable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwben
c --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-
libxvid --enable-zlib

  libavutil      52. 13.100 / 52. 13.100
  libavcodec     54. 86.100 / 54. 86.100
  libavformat    54. 59.106 / 54. 59.106
  libavdevice    54.  3.102 / 54.  3.102
  libavfilter     3. 32.100 /  3. 32.100
  libswscale      2.  1.103 /  2.  1.103
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100

Unrecognized option 'bframebias'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

Comment: Please include your actual ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output.

Comment: Added above, please check!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you declaring a legion of x264 options with seemingly random settings, and then adding an encoding preset? It is recommended to simply use the x264 presets instead of trying to tweak each and every option.

#### Why use presets?

The presets:

- were designed by the x264 developers
- are kept up to date with any option changes, deletions, and additions
- are easier to use

Do you know what `-bframebias` (or `--b-bias` if using x264 cli directly) does? Did you know that `0` is the default value? Did you know that `-bframebias` has been depreciated for the `b-bias` libx264 private option?

This is exactly why you should use presets. You will not have to fight with option changes (as much) and you don't have to know what every option does because the presets will deal with it for you.

#### A simpler and cleaner command

Your command, for example, can probably be simplified to:

```
ffmpeg -i input -codec:v libx264 -b:v 1500k -profile:v main -level 41 -preset fast -codec:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k -ac 2 -vf scale=720:-1 output.mkv
```

Although I doubt you need `-profile:v main -level 41`, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, and I recommend usage of `-crf` instead of `-b:v`.

#### Choosing a preset

For most purposes you want to use the slowest `-preset` you have patience for and the highest `-crf` value that still gives an acceptable quality. See the [FFmpeg and x264 Encoding Guide](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide) for more information and examples.

#### Changing the preset defaults

If you feel that you do need to tweak the options, then use the proper libx264 private AVOptions (as shown in `ffmpeg -h full` or `ffmpeg -h encoder=libx264`) or use the `-x264-params` option.  See the example in [Overwriting default x264 preset settings](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#Overwritingdefaultpresetsettings).

Comment: Do you know any replacements for the '-bframebias' option?? Thanks.

Comment: @RRN Why do you want to use this option?

Comment: Since I saw some ffmpeg command for encoding video to ios devices, it includes this option, so I would like to retain it.

Comment: @RRN No need to blindly copy crappy, outdated examples from the net. This option is default anyway, AFAIK. Which iOS devices in particular are you interested in supporting?

Comment: @RRN Please be more specific if possible since there are several versions of iPhone and iPad, and some do not support specific features while others do.

Comment: I want iPhone3 and 5, iPad1 and 3.  Actually where may I find those information?

Comment: @RRN See [Preparing Media for Delivery to iOS-Based Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW8). It's streaming specific, but the info should also be applicable to regular file playback.

Comment: but I think the bitrate and framerate won't be same...